# Use the file types image of the operating system in C# .NET

Tags: c#, .net, windows, icons, file-type

Can I use somehow the filetype images from my operating system and display them in my application?

Comment: Check out this article on CodeProject http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/GetFileTypeAndIcon.aspx

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get common file type icons in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/616718/how-do-i-get-common-file-type-icons-in-c)

Answer (score 2):

If you know the file name of the file whose icon you want, you can use the [`ExtractAssociatedIcon`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.icon.extractassociatedicon.aspx) function for that purpose. e.g.

```
Icon ico = Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(@"C:\WINDOWS\system32\notepad.exe");
```

There is a catch to this method though. According to its documentation,

> When ExtractAssociatedIcon is used with bitmaps, a thumbnail image may be returned instead of an icon if the system that is running the application has a registry setting that causes bitmap files to be shown as thumbnail images.

One other thing I found was that this method only extracts 32x32pixel icons.

See [System.Drawing.Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.icon.extractassociatedicon.aspx) for more how to use this method.

---

For a more robust icon extractor, I'd suggest you look at the [OSIcon](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/OSIcon.aspx) project on CodeProject.
It allows you to get the associated icon of any file using its file name *or* extension.
Here is a sample code for doing that:

```
OSIcon.WinAPI.Shell32.SHFILEINFO shfi = new Shell32.SHFILEINFO();
Icon icon = OSIcon.IconReader.GetFileIcon(".png", IconReader.IconSize.Large, false, ref shfi);
```

This is the link to the project: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/OSIcon.aspx